# Weekly competition

Tags: node.js, reactjs, date

I have a website running on the MERN stack.
On the frontend I want to declare a weekly competition. The question is that how will I know if a week is started or ended.
I came up with a solution. I post the current date to the database and then get it on the frontend. From there, I use date-fns (npm) to find the days difference as the days passes. Once the difference reached 7. I make a new competition.
But the problem is that I have to make schemas for dates and then how can I send the date from the server if there are a lot of schemas after some weeks.
Please tell me a good idea to do the same thing.

Comment: Also tell me if I should use date-fns in production

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be that someone manually starts a weekly competition. Maybe you could add a timer to for the admin that notifies him that it's time to start a competition.

Comment: @Joytim it definitely needs to be started automatically